# preload datauri images in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, data-uri

With javascript, how I can preload images that dont have a path source but a datauri as its source?

I have something like this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
```

I want to do this on https pages but getting an error that i have a mixture of secure and nonsecure items on the page. Any ideas why this may the case and any way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You're sure that it's the presence of just *this* image that causes the problem? And is this JavaScript within the https document itself, or another document (if it's another from another JS file, is that file served via https?)?

Comment: Oh, and another thing, how on earth is this preloading? If you got the image-data, that means the image is already loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insecure error occurs anytime you reference any offsite or non-https file. This is why generally you want to link to images/CSS/etc by reference (an absolute path containing 'http://' would give the same error). Depending on certain browsers security policy, images created with base64 datauri's are seen as external and non-secure.

EDIT: In addition, I suggest you read this:

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html

It discusses a proposal for how you can specify what sorts of things are seen as secure an what is insecure. Specifically, try adding the following header:

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self'; img-src data:
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue seems to be only occuring with IE7, not IE8 or 9, so it is possible that the security policy of IE7, datauri's are seen as external or non secure. Do you know if IE7 supports X-Content-Security-Policy? I could possibly use this to work around my issue.

Comment: Nope, I believe it only works in Firefox. New releases of webkit-based browsers also need the X-WebKit-CSP header, but I myself have not played with it (only the X-Content-Security-Policy header)

Comment: Also for woff base64 in self css add: font-src 'self' data:;